# twitterAPI python error : No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, twitter

I'm using twitterAPI python wrapper https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI

```
    CONSUMER_KEY = ''
    CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
    ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = ''
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

    api = TwitterAPI(
                    CONSUMER_KEY,
                    CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                    # auth_type='oAuth1',
                    # proxy_url=None
    )
    r = api.request('account/verify_credentials')
    print(r.text)
```

This is working fine I'm getting proper response so I tried to use filter api of twitter 
'statuses/filter'  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter
with 'follow' parameter

`lst = api.request('statuses/filter', {'follow': 'some_user_id'})`  #user_id = 123456789, some 9 digit number

I print type of this object   `print(type(lst))`  and I get
`<class 'TwitterAPI.TwitterAPI.TwitterResponse'>`

but when I try to access methods of this class it gives me error `No JSON object could be decoded`
you can find all the methods of this class here http://twitterapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I have tried all 4 methods `print(lst.get_iterator())` ,... ,`print(lst.text)` but same error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you `print(lst.status_code)`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a TwitterResponse object with

```
lst = api.request('statuses/filter', {'follow': 'some_user_id'})
```

you can iterate the returned stream of statuses using

```
for item in lst:
  print(item['text'])
```

You can also get the HTTP status code using

```
print(lst.status_code)
```

However, `print(lst.text)` will not work because statuses/filter uses a continuous streaming  connection.